Finding positive vectors of a special LGS
Let the following $4 \times 4$ LGS be given for which all coefficients
$a_1, a_2, a_3, a_{11}, a_{12}, ..., a_{33}$ are $>0$:
$a_1 + a_{11} \; x_1 + a_{12} \; x_2 +  a_{13} \; x_3 + 0 \; x_4 = (a_{11}+a_{21}+a_{31}+a_{41}) \; x_1$
$a_2 + a_{21} \; x_1 + a_{22} \; x_2 +  a_{23} \; x_3 + 0 \; x_4 =(a_{12}+a_{22}+a_{32}+a_{42}) \; x_2$
$a_3 + a_{31} \; x_1 + a_{32} \; x_2 +  a_{33} \; x_3 + 0 \; x_4 =(a_{13}+a_{23}+a_{33}+a_{43})x_3 $ 
$a_4 + a_{41} \; x_1 + a_{42} \; x_2 +  a_{43} \; x_3 + 0 \; x_4 =a_{44} \; x_4 $
and the corresponding matrix:
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-a_{21}-a_{31}-a_{41} & a_{12} & a_{13} & 0 \\
a_{21} & -a_{12}-a_{32}-a_{42} & a_{23} & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & -a_{13}-a_{23}-a_{43} & 0 \\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & -a_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix}$
then:
1)
The determinant is not equal to $0$ (i.e. there is exactly one solution).
2)
The solution is positive (all elements of the vector are $> 0$ )
My question:
Can this be generalized to any $n \times n$ LGS ( $\geq4$ ) ?
best regards
carlo

What about the signs of the coefficients $a_{41}\dots a_{44}$? What do you mean by "the solution is positive"? Is there a given right-hand side?

What is an LGS, please?




linear system of equations = LGS



You can write the LGS in matrix form:
$\begin{pmatrix}
-a_{21}-a_{31}-a_{41} & a_{12} & a_{13} & 0 \
a_{21} & -a_{12}-a_{32}-a_{42} & a_{23} & 0 \
a_{31} & a_{32} & -a_{13}-a_{23}-a_{43} & 0 \
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & -a_{44} \
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\
x_2\
x_3\
x_4\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-a_1\
-a_2\
-a_3\
-a_4\\end{pmatrix}
$ \ \ \

LGS stands for linear system of equations? In which language, please?

Question about the same system of equations on mathstack, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977050/finding-positive-vectors-of-a-special-lgs

Provided all the coefficients $a_{jk}$ you mentioned are positive, the answer is yes.

Gershgorin's disk theorem applied to the upper left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix shows that its eigenvalues are nonzero. Then Laplace's determinant formula teaches us that the determinant of $A$ is nonzero because $a_{nn}\neq0$.

Assume the coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of the RHS are all positive. By the zeros in the last column, the system is reducible by block-Gaussian elimination. Since the upper left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix is monotone, the coefficients $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$ will be positive. Now, you can solve for $x_n$ explicitly and it will necessarily be positive.



Thank you for your answer. I only require that all $a_{ij} >0$ and all $a_i > 0$ . Questions: 1)
Are then all $x_i > 0$? 2)
If not, is there a counterexample? best regards carlo

The inverse of $-A$ is positive iff that matrix is monotone, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_matrix . By setting $a_{44}$ very small and, say, $a_{41}$ large, you can easily violate this property.

$\begin{pmatrix}
-a_{21}-a_{31}-a_{41} & a_{12} & a_{13} & 0 \
a_{21} & -a_{12}-a_{32}-a_{42} & a_{23} & 0 \
a_{31} & a_{32} & -a_{13}-a_{23}-a_{43} & 0 \
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & -a_{44} \
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\
x_2\
x_3\
x_4\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-a_1\
-a_2\
-a_3\
-a_4\\end{pmatrix}
$
I set all $a_i$ and all coefficients $a_{ij}$  to 1, except $a_{41}$ and $a_{44}$: \
$a_{41} = 1000$ (large) and $t_4 = -1/1000$ (very small).
But Wolfram Alpha only provides a positive solution
(all $x_i > 0$)

Due to the special structure, you can indeed show that the solution is always positive. I have revised the above answer accordingly.

What ist the difference between "block-Gaussian elimination" and "Gaussian algorithmus" ?
Why ist the upper left $n-1$ x $n-1$ matrix monotone?
I can only prove that it has the Determinant unequal to 0.
best regards carlo

You easily check that it is strictly diagonally dominant and thus monotone, see the wiki page linked above. By block Gaussian I mean that $x_n$ plays no role in the first $n-1$ equations, so you solve them first and afterwards for $x_n$.
